# Ionic 2 ads banner campaign with tabs

Tags: typescript, tabs, ionic2, ads, banner

i want to add **ads banner campaign image** above `tabs` in `ionic 2`.

**So my question any idea about that or how i can create this banner at this position ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using `<ion-footer>`

```
<ion-content>
  ...
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
</ion-footer>
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toolbar/Footer/

To add it to every page, I would probably create a custom directive and add it to each page.

Alternatively, you can add it to the `tabs.html`:

```
<ion-footer style="margin-bottom: 42px;">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

You should put the style into the an scss file and adjust the margin to the height of the tabbar. However, I would still recommend to use the first option.

Comment: thank you for your response but i want to show footer in every page above the tabs how i can do it ?

Comment: perfect !!, but how i can adjust the height of the content with the banner ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what your problem is. You mean the content of the banner or the content of the page?